# Is there any adb command to disable android's display?

Tags: adb, display

Hi im looking for method to disable my android phones display running on pie. I don't want to use tap to sleep, power button or simulate that option but I want to simply disable display completely and then turn it back on when I need it. I have rooted my phone already.

Example: I want to watch a YouTube video with only audio. So if I disable the display it can save my battery but pressing power button stops the buffering.

it's just an example for what I want to do this. I don't want it. I'm aware of youtube vanced..

PS: I have non amoled display.

I'm thinking for the following methods (though I'm not an expert):

1. Make brightness zero.
2. Change display driver's file name with adb to disable or enable display.
3. Take code of android where it simply disables the display after pressing power key (without performing other functions).

I expect the display to be turned off exactly like when pressing power button, but without other tasks that happens with power button.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it works for you to install a Youtube client app.

Xiaomi app Mi Music (com.miui.player) allows you to reproduce a Youtube video in background and wih screen off.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miui.player

Comment: Youtube is an example, not the problem itself.